# ESC/POS raw print -á, -é, -í, -ó, -ú, -ü, -ñ, ¿, ¡ work locally ( Italy ) but not in Spain

Tags: java, character-encoding, epson, escpos

I receive a String from a web service, and I want to print it on an ESC/POS printer.  I tried this:

```
private void print()
{
    PrintService ps = getPrinter(deviceSystemName);
    byte[] commandByteArray = decodeReceiptCommandString();
    DocFlavor df = DocFlavor.INPUT_STREAM.AUTOSENSE;
    ByteArrayInputStream pis = new ByteArrayInputStream(commandByteArray);

    Doc d = new SimpleDoc(pis, df, null);
    if (ps != null) {
        DocPrintJob job = ps.createPrintJob();
        job.print(d, null); 
    }
}

private byte[] decodeReceiptCommandString()
{
    String encoding = "Cp850";
    String commandString = new String(this.receipt.getString("stringa"));
    return commandString.getBytes(encoding);
}
```

This works very well in an Italian system, but when I print on my customer's Spanish printer the result is not the same.

### My working print:

[image]

### As printed on my customer's printer:

[image]

The protocol and the charset of my printer is the same of my customer printer.

What's going wrong, and how do I fix it?

Comment: What is `this.receipt.getString("stringa")`, how is it initialized and where does it come from? If it is already a String, then using `new String()` on it doesn't make sense. If it comes from some config file make sure the file is read using the correct encoding.

Comment: this.receipt is a JSONObject, i must get the content with .getString( key ), key is a property of receipt JSONObject

receipt structure = {  id : int , stringa:String };

Comment: So have you checked that this string isn't already mangled before printing? My guess would be that the problem might be somewhere else...

Comment: Did you make sure that the printer is set to the same codepage as the data you send to it?  To set the Codepage 850, send ESC t 0x02 to the printer.

Comment: What printer (Brand, model) are you using?

Comment: I'm using ESPON TM T70

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution that can help. You should find what are the characters that your printer actually prints when you send a byte.

I tested this on a ESC POS HASAR 180 printer and I have realized that the characters are in a very strange order and there is no standard at all.

[image: Ticket with characters]

Here is my code:

```
static byte[] PrintChars() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (int i = 33; i < 256; i++)
    {
        sb.Append((char)i + "-");
    }
    sb.Append("\n");
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
}
```